# HDMI audio not working on desktop installation with 22.04 version

Tags: sound, software-installation, hdmi

I am new to Ubuntu and have installed the 22.04 version on an HP slime line machine. When I did a trial with a usb flash drive that I created from an ISO I downloaded, the HDMI port audio and video worked fine. In the settings app under sound the output setting read `HDMI video and built in Audio Port`.

After the full clean install, the Output setting read `Dummy Output`. I have tried all the suggestions I read here on line with no success. I tried the usb flash drive trial again after the install and it worked fine. I did another clean install and still no sound and still reading `Dummy Output`. Any ideas?

Comment: You didn't specify which 22.04 ISO you used (I gather it was Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop, but 22.04? 22.04.1? or 22.04.2?) as I wonder if your *live* system was using a different kernel to your first (& subsequent) boot.  Ubuntu 22.04 & 22.04.1 media used the 5.15 kernel for example; 22.04.2 used 5.19, with all upgrading to 5.19 (*which differs to flavors of Ubuntu 22.04*).. as this maybe will provide an easy fix; ie. use the older GA kernel stack; at least until you find a *fix* for the HWE kernel stack.

Comment: thank you for your response. How do i use the older ga kernal?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack   You didn't say what 22.04 ISO you installed with, but I'd expect at boot you can select the kernel your *live* or *installation media* installed with at grub, unless the install was made awhile ago & you've been updating the system (*only a couple of kernels are kept*).  5.15 is the GA kernel & default for Server installs & *flavor* installs using original media, HWE changes to use later stacks from later releases (5.19 at 22.04.2 is the stack from Ubuntu 22.10). Both GA & HWE stacks can co-exist unless you're using some closed-source modules

Comment: My version is 22.04.02. Thank you for your help. I was able to check what kernel I had and it was 15.19.035 I then installed 15 15.101 and rebooted. On boot up I went to advanced ubuntu and saw 15.19.032. I then loaded that kernel and that fixed my problem. I am not at all familiar with linux code but have learned a lot in the last two days. It reminds me of my early days with windows ouch.